# Ignore pagination and page break leading slow report rendering

Tags: pagination, jasper-reports, export-to-excel

I have sub reports placed on a main report

1. given is ignore pagination to true and placed break element after the sub   report(to split sub reports in separate excel worksheets).
2. given local  anchors for each sub reports in the background band.
3. Deployed the report on jasper server.

I am getting each report in each worksheets and the excel export is perfect.But in  the report rendering page it is not breaking,as we given ignore pagination and it slower the whole report and anchoring.(evry page in the sub report renders in one page of jasper server almost 500 pages )

My question is do we have any option to break only for excel export???
Note :- I have tried with the property export.xls.break.after.row. and it is breaking sheets perfectly but the excel columns got merged.so I opted page break element from the palette
Please give a solution .

Answer (score 0):

The property to set or avoid new sheet on page break in excel is

```
net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.one.page.per.sheet=false
```

So you can try to remove ignore pagination and setting this property to false.

These are the available properties [config.reference](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/config.reference.html)

Comment: I have tried this one and got the work sheets.But what happens is My columns are merged and coming in same shape for all the worksheets.

Comment: aaah ok in question I only see "export.xls.break.after.row"

Comment: any script to print break element only when exporting to xls and take ignore pagination to true only when xls export??? I knwow it looks a bit tricky but if you can ..please give me a solution,,,

Comment: The problem is that you are using jasper server, if you had your only application it would be more simple... you could add reports to list when excel....

Comment: @harunprasu You could try to see if in scriplet you understand if you are exporting to excel (maybe jasper report server put some parameter in the request)... then make a method in scriplet that can be called by printWhenExpression

Comment: beforeReportInit() , super.parametersMap.keySet(); see if you find some useful parameter set by the jasper report servlet....

Comment: You mean Parameters that pass when we opt export to xls? right? I have created  a sample scriptlet and called a method inside the scriptlet in a image expression but ist says method() is undefined for the type JRDefaultScriptlet

Comment: You need to make a class extending the scriplet add it to jrxml (scriptletClass) and then you override methods as in comment above trying to understand if jasper report server put some nice parameter you can use to understand that its exporting to excel...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100788/discussion-between-harun-prasu-and-petter-friberg).